# What is the correct name for this chip? And how to read it?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I seen this type of chip on credit cards and various other electronics like printers. What is it called in the electronics field? Is there a specific protocol on how to read and write to it? Is there a reader/writer machine? Software?

[image]

Comment: That is a connector. There could be any sort of chip connected to it internally.

Comment: Does this connector has a set name? How can I get the matching connector?

Comment: [SIM/SmartCard Connector](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?channel=products&key=sim__smart_card)

Comment: is there any industry standard for the pinout? As far as GND, power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a smart-card contact interface. They don't have a specific name, but they are specified in the ISO/IEC 7816-2.

You'll find the electrical protocol specified in ISO 7816-3. In a nutshell it is not too different to RS232 serial communication with the difference that the RX and TX lines are shared on one pin, and that a multiple of the baud rate has to be provided as an external clock.

You can buy reader devices pretty much anywhere.

Comment: Also, the whole point of a smart card is you don't just 'read' it like a memory chip, so a 'smart card reader' is rather a misnomer.  The smart card contains cryptographic signatures that are actively protected and cannot be read directly, only used as a part of a cryptographic handshake to validate the card.  This makes it very difficult to duplicate a smart card or perform replay attacks.

Comment: Are there any known systems to crack the handshake? Something like reaver Reaver-WPS for Wi-Fi?

Comment: I got a cheap catd reader and my credit card was recognized. But when I tried this chip it didnt recognize it. Is the pinout standardized? I removed the glue from the mcu unit and found markings on it (different post), any chance you recognize it? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/174225/26231

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of types of ICs that are used in SmartCard applications.  Microcontrollers and serial access EEPROMS are amongst the most popular.  Some are secured from simple reading and/or writing and some are NOT.  There is no reason to suppose that a secure chip would give away a part number on the die on purpose.